# What's the `save()` for in Django?

Tags: django

I am learning Django and have the following codes:

```
def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        #Redisplay the question voting form
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question':question,
            'error_message':"You did'nt select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

I am confused about the `selected_choice.save()`, as a simple example:

```
counter = 0
for counter in range(9):
    counter += 1
    print(counter)
```

There's no `save` operation during the process.

What's the `save()` for in Django?

Comment: save() sync data from memory to db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start a level higher.  Everything said by others is true, but I think you may be getting lost in the abstractions presented by Django.

Your get object_or_404 is an abstraction on the following psuedo code:

```
try:
    question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id) #grabing this row from the questions table in the db
except:
     return 404 url
```

Your example was then iterating the selected_choice and incrementing that value AND then saving it to the db.  The simple counter counter-example only has a print statement which doesn't update the db.

At the risk of overstepping, I'd recommend starting with the core django tutorials - then trying something more complex.  I believe with a little more foundation (which I know is an investment) that foundation will pay dividends in getting the abstractions.

Answer (score 1):

**What's the save() for in Django?**

`send/sync/save` an object to the database.
When you save an object, The following steps have been triggered:

1. pre_save signal (Time for any functions listening for that signal to execute)
2. Preprocess the data (Each field that has `pre_save` method is called)

   *i.e : For example, the date/time fields override pre_save() to implement auto_now_add and auto_now.*
3. Prepare the data for the database
4. Insert the data into the database
5. Emit a post-save signal (Time for any functions listening for that signal to execute)

Source: [Django Official Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects)

Answer (score 0):

The keyword arguments are simply the names of the fields you’ve defined on your model. Note that instantiating a model in no way touches your database; for that, you need to save().
So basically the save method is to sync your data(updated data) to your database, without saving you are not able to see the updated data in your database.